# WebdriverIO Browser.click statement gives is not a function error

Tags: automation, webdriver-io

I am fairly new to WebDriverIO framework, I was trying to automate below scenario:

```
const assert = require('assert');

describe('Second Test With WebDriverIO', () => {

    it('Click the button for WebDriverIO Page', () => {

        browser.url('http://www.kevinlamping.com/webdriverio-course-content/');
        var title = browser.getTitle();
        assert.strictEqual(title,'Robot Parts Emporium');
        //browser.click('.shop-callout a');
        $('.shop-callout a').click();
        title = browser.getTitle();
        assert.strictEqual(title,'Totally Not Evil Sentient Robot - Robot Parts Emporium');

    });
});
```

However, I get an error mentioning `"[chrome  windows nt #0-0] browser.click is not a function"`

But I use `$('.shop-callout a').click();` instead of `browser.click('.shop-callout a');` then it all works fine.

```
const assert = require('assert');

describe('Second Test With WebDriverIO', () => {

    it('Click the button for WebDriverIO Page', () => {

        browser.url('http://www.kevinlamping.com/webdriverio-course-content/');
        var title = browser.getTitle();
        assert.strictEqual(title,'Robot Parts Emporium');
        //browser.click('.shop-callout a');
        $('.shop-callout a').click();
        title = browser.getTitle();
        assert.strictEqual(title,'Totally Not Evil Sentient Robot - Robot Parts Emporium');

    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `browser.elementClick(elementId)`, instead of `browser.click()`, as this is the correct method name as per webdriver protocol.

See below:-

https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#element-click

`$(selector).click()` is a custom method provided by webdriverio and they have used the same method as mentioned above.